# UDF inside an SP performance issue on ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SP

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[order_s]
(
    @user Uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
      id,
      name,
      [begin],
      [end]
FROM 
      orders 
WHERE
    @user = dbo.hasAccess(@user,id,'select')
END
```

This SP calls a this UDF

```
    FUNCTION [dbo].[hasAccess] 
    (
        @user uniqueidentifier,
        @orderId bigint,
        @AccessType nchar(10)
    )
    RETURNS uniqueidentifier
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result uniqueidentifier

        SELECT 
            Top 1 @Result = [user] 
        FROM 
            access 
        WHERE 
            orderId = @orderId AND
            [user] = @user AND
            role >= CASE    
                        WHEN @AccessType = 'select' then 1
                        WHEN @AccessType = 'insert' then 5
                        WHEN @AccessType = 'update' then 7
                        WHEN @AccessType = 'delete' then 10
                    END
        RETURN @Result
END
```

My question is, calling an UDF from an SP have any performance issues?
Is there a better way to achieve the same functionality?

Thanks for your advise...

Comment: Calling a UDF from a SP has no issues. Calling from a where clause does. It will call the UDF once for every row in `orders`.

Comment: Yep. Didn't notice that to begin with this will be much better off inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a bad use of scalar UDFs. This should perform much better.

```
SELECT 
      id,
      name,
      [begin],
      [end]
FROM 
      orders o
WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT  *   
            FROM access         
            WHERE orderId = o.id AND [user] = @user AND role >= 1
           )
```

[Some discussion on Scalar UDFs and performance here](http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/general/2010/questions/sqlserver-quiz-general-2010-adam-haines-how-can-scalar-functions-cause-performance-problems-when-used-in-the-select-list-join-expression-or-where-clause.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As always with questions re: performance- profile, profile, profile.

Other than that, the only reason I can see that a UDF would cause any performance problems was if it, itself, was particularly inefficient.  It should be no less efficient than calling `GetDate()` in a Stored Proc.

Comment: RE: Your last line Scalar UDFs (especially that do data access) are notoriously inefficient in SQL Server! See for example [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx) and [TSQL Scalar functions are evil.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/11/03/TSQL-Scalar-functions-are-evil-.aspx)

Comment: This is a poor answer because there are known performance issues with this pattern.